# to align check box in group of four in HTML

Tags: html, css

#### HTML code

```
<div  id=checkbox>
    <div id=groupfour>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jan" id="EJan">
            <label>Jan </label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Feb" id="EFeb">
            <label>Feb</label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Mar" id="EMar">
            <label>Mar</label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Apr" id="EApr">
            <label>Apr</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id=groupfour>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="May" id="EMay">
            <label>May</label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jun" id="EJun">
            <label>Jun</label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jul" id="EJul">
            <label>Jul </label>
        </div>
        <div id=groupone>
            <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Aug" id="EAug">
            <label>Aug</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### CSS Code

```
#groupfour
{
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I want to group my checkboxes of months  in group of four in three rows .  This way its coming in a vertical list of months .If I remove internal div checkboxes are not alligned in all three rows .

Comment: Do you have a diagram of some sort of what you want?

Comment: The markup is invalid; `id` attribute values must be unique. This probably causes serious problems at least in some browsers.

Comment: can u show ur copde in jsfiddle

Comment: you have 2 group here.how you can show in 3 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/igivah/1/)

Its very very basic way to make this

Comment: @MahdiParsa because he can check the output in that link

Answer (score 0):

**Used to** `white-space:nowrap` **and** `display:inline-block;`

as like this

```
#groupfour{
white-space:nowrap;
}

#groupfour #groupone{
display:inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dPjBy/)**

**[Demo-2](http://jsfiddle.net/dPjBy/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved that using css

```
<style>
.groupone{
    float: left;
}
.groupfour{
    clear: left;
}
</style>
```

Also, since you are calling same div at the same time, change all 'id' to 'class'

```
<div class="groupfour">
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jan" class="EJan">
                    <label>Jan </label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Feb" class="EFeb">
                    <label>Feb</label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Mar" class="EMar">
                    <label>Mar</label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Apr" class="EApr">
                    <label>Apr</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="groupfour">
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="May" class="EMay">
                    <label>May</label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jun" class="EJun">
                    <label>Jun</label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Jul" class="EJul">
                    <label>Jul </label>
                </div>
                <div class="groupone">
                    <input type="checkbox"  checked="checked" name="Mapmashup" value="Aug" class="EAug">
                    <label>Aug</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```